# Accessing variables declared in another file

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm a newbie to NSIS and started working with CoolSoft NSIS dialog Designer to create custom pages for my installer. I have a requirement to hide/unhide some textboxes according to user's selection from a dropdown box. I have included my the custom page in my main nsis script file but seems like i cannot access the variables defined in my custom page.

So my question is whether it's possible to access a variable defined in another script which is included in the current script?

Comment: It would really help if you included the compiler error in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables in NSIS are global, you should be able to use any variable after it has been declared:

foo.nsh:

```
var myvar
```

bar.nsi:

```
!include foo.nsh
...
section
strcpy $myvar "baz"
sectionend
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declared the variable inside of the custom page, did you declared the variable as global? The manual states for [variables](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.2.1.1) that:

> variables defined in a section or a function must use the /GLOBAL flag. The /GLOBAL flag is not required outside of sections and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use **/GLOBAL** flag for declaring variables - they will become visible from everywhere.

```
Var /GLOBAL myVariable
```

If you want to use Symbols (not variables) from different script file then you need to use **!include** to tell compiler to use symbols from that file.

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
```